# VBScript unable to read string from Array

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently writing a fairly simple script to manage a network program installation. As part of this installation, I need to read the IP addresses currently assigned to any live adapters.

I can read the IP addresses without issue, however I'm now struggling to read the addresses found from the array I've loaded them into. I do this in several other scripts without issue, so am really stumped as to what I've done wrong. My script is as below:

```
'Object declarations
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colIPConf = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = 'True'")

'Check local IP addresses
Z = 0
Dim arrAdapters()

For Each objIPConf In colIPConf
    ReDim Preserve arrAdapters(Z)
    arrAdapters(Z) = objIPConf.IpAddress
    test = arrAdapters(Z) 
    msgbox test ' TYPE MISMATCH HERE
    Z = Z+1 
Next
```

I don't understand why my "test" variable is giving a type mismatch for use in a MsgBox? When I place a breakpoint in VbsEdit and inspect my test variable - it is not showing a single string value, but an array with position 0 and a value attached. Why is this the case when I'm specifying

```
test = arrAdapters(Z)
```

Surely it should just be plucking the string from the array?

Comment: This has definitely be answered before, gonna go look for the dup.

Comment: If it's a dup feel free to mark it, I did have a look before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBscript for use with multiple IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070715/vbscript-for-use-with-multiple-ip-addresses)

Comment: Possibly related  [Script is obtaining wrong NIC IP details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36221073/692942)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IpAddress` property is an array already in VBScript. You can check it using [`VarType` and/or `TypeName` functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ca8tfek(v=vs.84).aspx), e.g. as follows:

```
Option Explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sResult: sResult = Wscript.ScriptName

'Object declarations
Dim objFSO, objWMIService, colIPConf
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colIPConf = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = 'True'")

'Check local IP addresses
Dim ii, arrAdapters, objIPConf

For Each objIPConf In colIPConf
    sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & objIPConf.Description
    arrAdapters = objIPConf.IpAddress
    sResult = sResult _
              & vbTab & VarType( arrAdapters) & vbTab & TypeName( arrAdapters)
    For ii = 0 To UBound(arrAdapters)
        sResult = sResult & vbNewLine & arrAdapters( ii) 
    Next
Next
Wscript.Echo sResult
Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `arrAdapters(Z) = objIPConf.IpAddress` might be returning an array and not a string.

Change your code to `arrAdapters(Z) = objIPConf.IpAddress(0)` and it should work. Or you can check for an array using `IsArray(objIPConf.IpAddress)` before doing any assignment.